# How to get token_for_business for Facebook login - iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

How can I get `token_for_business` from Facebook login? I have setup a business and associated my application with that business. Facebook documentation says you need to call `GET /me?fields=token_for_business` on User node, and it will return following json.

```
{
  "id": "1234567890"
  "token_for_business": "weg23ro87gfewblwjef"
}
```

I tried by providing `token_for_business` in parameter list of `/me` call but didn't work. Need advises.

**Edit**
I found this URL `https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/user` and tried by passing `token_for_business` in param of `initWithGraphPath` but no gain. I checked in Graph API Explorer and getting the required data. But not sure how to call from my objective-C code.

**Edit 2**
I Inspected the error object of `initWithGraphPath:@"me?fields=token_for_business"` call and found following details

```
Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk.core Code=8 "(null)" UserInfo={com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorCategoryKey=0, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorHTTPStatusCodeKey=403, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorDeveloperMessageKey=(#200) Application must be associated with a business. https://business.facebook.com/, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorGraphErrorCode=200, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorParsedJSONResponseKey={
    body =     {
        error =         {
            code = 200;
            "fbtrace_id" = "EN9bN/YMloA";
            message = "(#200) Application must be associated with a business. https://business.facebook.com/";
            type = OAuthException;
        };
    };
    code = 403;
}}
```

But if I try my app in Graph API Explorer then I'm getting the required data. So now it confusing me.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct app id in your code?

Comment: yes .. before this change the fb login was working fine. The "me" graphPath returns fb id and profile info. But this id is different for different platforms  (Android,  iOS) hence I need to implement business token.

Comment: So you are using different app ids for Android and iOS? (Why?) When you try in Graph API Explorer, are you using the same app id (as your iOS app) there?

Comment: same fb app id in both Android and iOS.

Comment: Can you provide your app ID(s) here, please? I can check if it's set up correct.

Comment: can we talk privately? Thanks